# Circular Dependency with two depending Services

Tags: c#, .net, rest, dependency-injection, webassembly

I'm very new in C# and Dependency Injection. Currently I'm working on a new project and want to do a technology step forward.

In this Project, I've three situation causing circular dependency.

I've read a lot about this and found solutions like `Lazy<T>` and and `IServiceProvider`, but I want to learn a clean solution for this problem and want to follow the most common suggestion to refactor the code.

We have four services in this example:

`AccountService` -> Login, Logout and so on

`HttpService` -> Do the API-Stuff

`LogService` -> Do some logging

`LogRepository` -> CRUD for the logging table / wrapper for EF

The `AccountService` authenticate via API using `HttpService`. Later, I want use the `HttpService` to get more data via API. `HttpService` now need the `AccountService` to get the Token for authenticate the request. This is causing a circular dependency error.

AccountService

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    Identity Identity { get; }
    Task Login(Credentials Credentials);
    Task Logout();
}

public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    public Identity Identity { get; private set; }
    
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;
    private readonly ILogService _logService;
    
    public AccountService(
        IHttpService HttpService, ILogService LogService)
    {
        _httpService = HttpService;
        _logService = LogService;
    }

    public async Task Login(Credentials Credentials)
    {
        Identity = await _httpService.Post<Identity>(
            "api/rest/v1/user/authenticate", Credentials);
    }
}
```

HttpService

```
public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
    Task Post(string uri, object value);
    Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value);
}

public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
    private readonly ILogService _logService; 

    public HttpService(
        HttpClient HttpClient,
        IAccountService AccountService,
        ILogService ILogService)
    {
        _httpClient = HttpClient;
        _accountService = AccountService;
        _logService = LogService;
    }

    private async Task AddAuthentication(HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "bearer", _accountService.Identity.SystemToken);
    }
}
```

How is the best practice to solve or proper redesign this?

I've more Circular Dependency, e.g. use the `LogService` in `LogRepository` or using `LogService` in `HttpService` (because the `HttpService` sends Log-Entrys to the Server).

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you update your code samples in such way that: 1. you remove all dependencies that are irrelevant to the question and 2. trimmed down versions of the methods that are relevant to the cyclic dependency, i.e. show the method(s) of `AccountService` that call `HttpService`, and show the methods of `HttpService` that call into `IAccountService`.

Comment: That said, without knowing the details I'm willing to bet that either your `AccountService` or `HttpService` is doing too much, in other words, violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Splitting such class up into multiple smaller classes would often fix both the SRP violation and the cyclic dependency issue. I discuss this in detail in [section 6.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/259) of my book.

Comment: I've edited the code. You can now see the calls. The Services don't do that much. The HttpService only handels the api calls and the AccountService do only login, logout and holds informations about the current user.

Comment: Without knowing a lot about your system it seems like `HttpService` isn't that valuable and may be over-engineered.  I suggest removing this class entirely and create `HttpClient` in each service you need to make HTTP calls instead.

Comment: There is a nuget package to solve this https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.SmartInject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object graph where there is a cycle can't be satisfied by your DI Container, just like you would be unable to express this in plain old C#:

```cs
new AccountService(
    new HttpService(
        new AccountService(
            new HttpService(
                new AccountService(
                    new HttpService(
                        new AccountService(
                            new HttpService(
                                ... this would go on for ever
```

Although your *object graph* is cyclic (`AccountService` -> `HttpService` -> `AccountService`) your *call graph* is not. The call likely is something as follows:

```
AccountService.Login
    -> HttpService.Post
        -> HttpService.AddAuthentication
            -> AccountService.Identity
```

Cyclic *object graphs* with non-cyclic *call graphs* often happen on components that violate the [Single Responsibly Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). The more functionality (the more methods) classes get, the bigger the chance their object graphs become cyclic. Splitting classes up in smaller, more-focused pieces, not only fixes the cyclic-dependency problem, but often also improves the maintainability of the application.

I think your case is actually quite similar to the example that I discuss in [section 6.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/259) of [DIPP&P](https://cuttingedge.it/book). That section specifically talks about fixing cyclic dependencies.

Long story short, I think your best bet is to split `AccountService` in (at least) two services:

- One service responsible of logging in and logging out
- A second service responsible of getting the user's identity.

Both services get their own interface and those new interfaces are now less wide compared to `IAccountService`. This improves your chances of adhering to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Here's an example of how that looks like:

Let's start with the new interface definitions:

```cs
// Contains Login and Logout methods of old IAccountService
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    Task Login(Credentials Credentials);
    Task Logout();
}

// Contains Identity property of old IAccountService
public interface IIdentityProvider
{
    // For simplicity I added a setter to the interface, because that keeps
    // the example simple, but it is possible to keep Identity read-only if
    // required.
    Identity Identity { get; set; }
}

// This interface is kept unchanged.
public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
    Task Post(string uri, object value);
    Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value);
}
```

Let's look at the implementations next, starting with the `IAuthenticationService` implementation:

```cs
// Old AccountService, now depending on IIdentityProvider
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;
    private readonly ILogService _logService;
    private readonly IIdentityProvider _identityProvider;
    
    public AccountService(
        IHttpService HttpService,
        ILogService LogService,
        IIdentityProvider IdentityProvider)
    {
        _httpService = HttpService;
        _logService = LogService;
        _identityProvider = IdentityProvider;
    }

    public async Task Login(Credentials Credentials)
    {
        _identityProvider.Identity = await _httpService.Post<Identity>(
            "api/rest/v1/user/authenticate", Credentials);
    }
}
```

This "new" `AuthenticationService` contains part of the code of the `AccountService` and the rest of the old `AccountService` logic is hidden behind the new `IIdentityProvider` abstraction, which is injected into `AuthenticationService`. This refactoring is very similar to the [Facade Service refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) (for an elaborate discussion on the Facade Service refactoring, see [section 6.1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/11) of DIPP&P).

`IdentityProvider` implements the new `IIdentityProvider` interface and contains the old logic from `AccountService`:

```cs
public class IdentityProvider : IIdentityProvider
{
    public Identity Identity { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, `HttpService` that now depends on `IIdentityProvider` instead of `IAccountService`:

```cs
// Now depends on IIdentityProvider instead of IAccountService
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IIdentityProvider _identityProvider;
    private readonly ILogService _logService; 

    public HttpService(
        HttpClient HttpClient,
        IIdentityProvider IdentityProvider,
        ILogService ILogService)
    {
        _httpClient = HttpClient;
        _identityProvider = IdentityProvider;
        _logService = LogService;
    }

    private async Task AddAuthentication(HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        // Now uses the new IIdentityProvider dependency instead
        // of the old IAccountService, which caused the cycle.
        Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "bearer", _identityProvider.Identity.SystemToken);
    }
}
```

Using this new design, the object graph is no longer cyclic and, when constructed in plain C#, can be constructed as follows:

```cs
var identity = new IdentityProvider();
var logger = new LogService();

new AccountService(
    new HttpService(
        new HttpClient(...),
        identity,
        logger),
    logger,
    identity);
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I'll buy your book to learn more about modern architecture :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider redesigning your application. However, there is a nuget package that gives you a direct fix for this Exception: [ConnectingApps.SmartInject](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.SmartInject) .

It uses Lazy Injection. This means the actual creation is postponed to the moment it is really needed.

To solve this problem, the code similar to this:

```cs
public class Something : ISomething
{
    private readonly Lazy<ISomethingElse> _somethingElse;
    public Something(Lazy<ISomethingElse> somethingElse)
    {
        _somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }
}
```

and

```cs
public class SomethingElse : ISomethingElse
{
    private readonly Lazy<ISomething> _something;
    public SomethingElse(Lazy<ISomething> something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is to add the collowing line of code to your `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddLazySingleton<ISomething, Something>();
```

Alternatively, you can use `AddLazyTransient` or `AddLazyScoped` instead.
Do not forget use the following namespace line:

```cs
using ConnectingApps.SmartInject;
```

Logically, you will need to use your own classes. The ones I provided are just examples.