# Error while validating the service descriptor: A circular dependency was detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have two classes, `AccountService`:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<CustomIdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly IMediaService _mediaService;

    public AccountService(
        UserManager<CustomIdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<CustomIdentityUser> signInManager,
        LinkGenerator linkGenerator,
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
        IMediaService mediaService,
        RoleManager<CustomIdentityRole> roleManager,
        IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
        _accessor = accessor;
        _mediaService = mediaService;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

and the other called `MediaService`:

```
public class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    private readonly IMediaRepository _mediaRepository;
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MediaService(
        IMediaRepository mediaRepository,
        IAccountService accountService,
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _mediaRepository = mediaRepository;
        _accountService = accountService;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}
```

I injected these two into the IoC layer to use:

```
services.AddScoped<IMediaService, MediaService>();
services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
```

But I get an error at runtime:

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Aroma_Shop.Application.Interfaces.IMediaService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Aroma_Shop.Application.Services.MediaService': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Aroma_Shop.Application.Interfaces.IMediaService'.

> Aroma_Shop.Application.Interfaces.IMediaService(Aroma_Shop.Application.Services.MediaService) -> Aroma_Shop.Application.Interfaces.IAccountService(Aroma_Shop.Application.Services.AccountService) -> Aroma_Shop.Application.Interfaces.IMediaService"}

I understand where the problem is, if you look at the two classes `AccountService` and `MediaService`, you will notice that within each of these two classes, I requested to inject the other class. In `AccountService` I requested from service to inject `MediaService`, and in `MediaService` I requested from service to inject `AccountService`

The service descriptor can't inject these two classes, because when it wants to inject `AccountService`, it needs a `MediaService` to generate an object from it, and when it wants to inject `MediaService`, it needs `AccountService` to generate an object from it.

If possible, please help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this two-way dependency? Seems a bit strange.

Comment: This hints a problem in architecture _in general_. There might be rare cases where you need a two-way dependency but I would struggle to eliminate it if possible. If you absolutely need it this way, you can implement a factory and give that as a dependency rather than the service itself.

Comment: You *Must Not* Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In The English Language ....

Comment: No its not strange , if you take a look in my codes you can see why I need to two-way dependency – SnowGroomer 
Sorry , I Capitalize all words in the last just for cleaning – marc_s

Comment: Of course, it is much better for me to divide the classes and move forward with decentralization, but this was not the answer to my question, and you just erased the problem, I thought to myself, if these questions are not answered correctly, this is it. To do but not that this is the answer to my questions! @Steven

Comment: I'm unsure how dividing the classes would *not* solve your problem as was demonstrated in the referenced answer. If my answer "erased the problem," why didn't this answer your question? I'm willing to add a specific answer that helps solving your question, but to be able to do this, please tell me how splitting the classes would *not* solve the problem? What makes your scenarios different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services

Answer (score 2):

Or if they are so interdependent, you can provide a single implementation for both services,  eg

```
AccountAndMediaService : IAccountService, IMediaService
```

Comment: No, they are not so interdependent , I inject MediaService in AccountService For Using Email and in MediaService I inject AccountService to relate the comment to the user

Comment: The source of the problem very like is a Single Responsibility Violation (SRP) (account service is too big). Merging it together with the media service might solve the cyclic dependency, but only exaggerates the SRP issue.

Comment: Transactions that cross multiple areas of responsibility should be driven from high-level business services.  So here IAccountService can depend on IMediaService, but if you need a method that uses the IMediaService and updates an Account, that belongs in IAccountService.

Answer (score 0):

You can also register factory to resolve the dependency. Some containers provide build in `Func` "factories" for registered services but with Microsoft's one you can do as simple as:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Func<IMediaService>>(c => c.GetRequiredService<IMediaService>);
```

And resolve `Func<IMediaService>` instead of `IMediaService` in `AccountService`:

```
public AccountService(... Func<IMediaService> mediaServiceFactory,...)
{
    ...
    _mediaService = mediaServiceFactory(); (or in place where it is called)
    ...
}
```

Also note that if you have some recursive call path you are just deferring it till the runtime, so in case of infinite recursion you end up with StackOverflow exception, so maybe it is worth of effort to some move parts of the reused functionality to another class to  prevent such circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you cannot have two classes requiring DI that injects each other, it's a little bit of a chicken and egg scenario.

As some other answers have mentioned, you can use a ServiceLocator pattern, but this is not advisable and is actually just a bandaid that hides the real issue.

The only way to solve this is to remove one of the dependencies. Without seeing what methods each are calling, I think it makes more sense to have AccountService dependant on the MediaService.

So with that said, whatever MediaService is calling inside AccountService, I would create a new service that satisfies that for *both* services. Let's say MediaService calls the AccountService to find the CurrentLoggedInAccount. I would create an ICurrentAccountService, and move the relevant method from the AccountService to this service. Then have AccountService and MediaService depend on this service.

No matter what, you have to refactor your code. It cannot be solved with a one line fix.

More info : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/09/14/dealing-with-circular-dependency-injection-references/