# How to fix a circular reference in .NET Core DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Running into a circular reference from DI into my business services. Not sure what the best way to go about this is. I unfortunately can't remove from either service as I need them in both.

Below is an example of of my problem (not my actual services).

CarService

```
public class CarService
{
    private readonly CarRepository _carRepository;
    private readonly RecallService _recallService;

    public CarService(CarRepository carRepository, RecallService recallService)
    {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
        _recallService = recallService
    }

    public void RemoveRecallForCar(Recall recall)
    {
      //code
    } 

    public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid) 
    {
         Car car = _carRepository.Get(carGuid);
         if (car.Model == "Ford")
         {
             _recallService.SendRecall(carGuid);
         }
    }
}
```

}

RecallService

```
public class RecallService
{
    private readonly RecallRepository _recallRepository;
    private readonly CarService _carService;

    public RecallService(RecallRepository recallRepository,CarService carService)
    {
        _recallRepository = recallRepository;
        _carService = carService
    }

   public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid)
   {
    // recall code
   }

    public GetRecalls() 
    {
        List<Recall> recalls = _recallRepository.Fetch(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
        foreach(var recall in recalls) 
        {
            _carService.RemoveRecallForCar(recall);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I expect to be able to inject services into services without circular references

Comment: You can't have this. DI can't solve a problem like this that you could not solve without it.

Comment: That's a very strong sign of bad design. The circular reference is caused by the code itself, not DI.You can't create such objects even with hand-written `new` calls unless you pass a `null` for either `CarService` or `RecallService`

Comment: We can abstract the functionality that a service depends on by introducing an interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code like below, it will help you fix the circular references issue.

**ICustomService.cs**

```
public interface ICustomService
{
    void SendRecall(Guid carGuid);
    void RemoveRecallForCar(Recall recall);
}
```

---

**RecallService.cs**

```
public class RecallService : ICustomService
{
    private readonly RecallRepository _recallRepository;
    private readonly CarService _carService;
 
    public RecallService(RecallRepository recallRepository, CarService carService)
    {
        _recallRepository = recallRepository;
        _carService = carService;
    }

    public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid)
    {
    }

    public GetRecalls()
    {
        List<Recall> recalls = _recallRepository.Fetch(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
        foreach(var recall in recalls) 
        {
            _carService.RemoveRecallForCar(recall);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveRecallForCar(Recall recall)
    {
    }
}
```

---

**CarService.cs**

```
public class CarService
{
    private readonly CarRepository _carRepository;
    private readonly ICustomService _customService;
 
    public CarService(CarRepository carRepository, ICustomService customService)
    {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
        _customService = customService;
    }

    public void RemoveRecallForCar(Recall recall)
    {
    } 

    public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid) 
    {
        Car car = _carRepository.Get(carGuid);
        if (car.Model == "Ford")
        {
            _customService .SendRecall(carGuid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Own way is, use **Autofac** or another DI library.

The other way ,*that not a good solution*, is you can divided your services to multiple services.

CarService1 :

```
 public class CarService1
    {
        private readonly CarRepository _carRepository;
 
        public CarrContactService(CarRepository carRepository)
        {
            _carRepository = carRepository;
        }

        public void RemoveRecallForCar(Recall recall)
        {
          //code
        } 
        
    }
```

CarService2:

```
public class CarService2
        {
            private readonly CarRepository _carRepository;
            private readonly RecallService _recallService;
     
            public CarrContactService(CarRepository carRepository, RecallService recallService)
            {
                _carRepository = carRepository;
                _recallService = recallService
            }
       
            public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid) 
            {
                 Car car = _carRepository.Get(carGuid);
                 if (car.Model == "Ford")
                 {
                     _recallService.SendRecall(carGuid);
                 }
            }
        }
```

RecallService :

```
public class RecallService
{
    private readonly RecallRepository _recallRepository;
    private readonly CarService1 _carService;

    public RecallService(RecallRepository recallRepository,CarService1 carService)
    {
        _recallRepository = recallRepository;
        _carService = carService
    }

   public void SendRecall(Guid carGuid)
   {
    // recall code
   }

    public GetRecalls() 
    {
        List<Recall> recalls = _recallRepository.Fetch(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
        foreach(var recall in recalls) 
        {
            _carService.RemoveRecallForCar(recall);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is CarrContactService in your code ?

Comment: I just copy from his code. :-)

Comment: Hi Soheil, it's not a good soultion.

Comment: I know it, but it works. 

Comment: Why would you say that dividing your services is *not* a good solution? I would say it is *they* solution, as I expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67741095/264697), because it fixes the SRP and ISP violations that the code has.