# Repository/Service Pattern Issues .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Having some architecture issues that I'm trying to work through. I need to find a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Below is a brief mockup of how my services/repos look. My problem is I am getting a circular reference when activating them. The problem is there is code in each service that I need for example in the LoadService I may need to trigger a method in the CustomerService and vice versa.

Need help to understand the best approach here. I am trying to get these services in a SRP as much as possible.

**LoadRepository**

```
public class LoadRepository 
{
    private readonly DBContext _DBContext;

    public LoadRepository(DBContext DBContext)
    {
        _DBContext = DBContext;
    }

    public override DbSet<LoadEntity> LoadDbSet()
    {
        return _DBContext.Load;
    }
}
```

**LoadService**

```
public class LoadService 
{
    private readonly LoadRepository _loadRepository;
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public LoadService(
        LoadRepository loadRepository,
        ICustomerService customerService
    ) 
    {
        _loadRepository = loadRepository;
        _customerService = customerService;
    }    
}
```

**CustomerRepository**

```
public class CustomerRepository 
{
    private readonly DBContext _DBContext;

    public CustomerRepository(DBContext DBContext)
    {
        _DBContext = DBContext;
    }

    public override DbSet<CustomerEntity> LoadDbSet()
    {
        return _DBContext.Customer;
    }
}
```

**CustomerService**

```
public class CustomerService 
{
    private readonly CustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    private readonly ILoadService _loadService;

    public CustomerService(
        CustomerRepository customerRepository,
        ILoadService loadService
    ) 
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _loadService = loadService;
    }    
}
```

Comment: a.) you should try hard to not need that kind of coupling. b) I can just assume that one or both services do things they shouldn't do and that functionality should be split into another services. Both existing services should then reference the new service and eliminate the cyclic dependency on the way.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience it is better to avoid dependencies on the same level referencing each other. Move common functionality into some helper classes and/or inject all needed repositories into the corresponding services. For example :

```
public class LoadService 
{
    private readonly LoadRepository _loadRepository;
    private readonly CustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public LoadService(
        LoadRepository loadRepository,
        CustomerRepository customerRepository
    ) 
    {
        _loadRepository = loadRepository;
        _customerRepository = customerService;
    }        
}
```

Another approach to mitigate the problem (if currently refactoring is to much of headache) - use lazy injection via factories, for example something like the following using factory via `Func`:

```cs
// default DI does not provide automatic Func registration
Services.AddScoped<Func<ICustomerService>>(sp => () => sp.GetRequiredService<>(ICustomerService))
```

```
public class LoadService 
{
    private readonly LoadRepository _loadRepository;
    private readonly Func<ICustomerService> _customerServiceFactory;


    public LoadService(
        LoadRepository loadRepository,
        Func<ICustomerService> customerService
    ) 
    {
        _loadRepository = loadRepository;
        _customerServiceFactory = customerService;
    }   
}
```

And when it is needed invoke the factory - `_customerServiceFactory().SomeMethod()`. Though note that this method can result in SO if you have cycle in invocations (i.e. `ICustomerService.Foo()` calls `ILoadService.Bar()` which calls `ICustomerService.Foo()`) which can be caught only in runtime.

Comment: My load service is pretty large, the entity is the parent to a lot of child tables so it needs access to multiple services/repositories. If I switched to use all repository's instead of services is that bad practice though? My Load service would essentially have upwards of 15+ repository's injected. I'm trying to follow the Single Responsibility Principal but when I create a Load it needs to also create x,y and z so its hard to follow that pattern without injecting the services or repos in there

Comment: @Dicpherrr it sounds like load service is already breaking SRP. Possibly you should break it up. Maybe looking into something like mediatr.