# Avoid Two Services Calling Each Other

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create an API using dependency injection where I have two services calling each other.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly ReviewCustomersContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IRequestService _requestService;
    private readonly IReviewService _reviewService;
    private readonly IDocumentService _documentService;
    private readonly IDeleteRequestService _deleteRequestService;

    public UserService(ReviewCustomersContext context, IMapper mapper, IRequestService requestService, IReviewService reviewService,
        IDocumentService documentService, IDeleteRequestService deleteRequestService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _requestService = requestService;
        _reviewService = reviewService;
        _documentService = documentService;
        _deleteRequestService = deleteRequestService;
    }
```

and

```
public class RequestService : IRequestService
{
    private readonly ReviewCustomersContext _context;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public RequestService(ReviewCustomersContext context, IUserService userService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userService = userService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

I get error messages about the fact that `UserService` is calling `RequestService` and `RequestService` is calling `UserService`.
Is there any solution to solve that except duplicate the code in the functions I use to a third class?

Comment: The solution would depend on what exactly it is, they need from each other. So, the question does not include enough information to give a non-generic answer.

Comment: Each service uses some of the functions in the other service.

Comment: I don't know what you expect to hear outside of "Yeah, you cannot do that. Extract the Functionality to a 3rd class."?

Comment: Or _maybe_ those two should actually be another two, cut along a different edge?

Comment: What are the exact error messages are you seeing? What you are doing might be weird, but I don't see a technical problem per se. Or are you talking about the constructor injection? Is your DI framework complaining about the mutual dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67741095/264697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to not use constructor injection but a property instead, so changing

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private IServiceB _serviceB;

    public ServiceA(IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        _service = serviceB;
    }

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

    public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;

    }
}
```

which doesn't work, into something like

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private IServiceB _serviceB;

    public ServiceA()
    {
    }
    public IServiceB 
    {
        get { return _serviceB; } 
        set { _serviceB = value; }
    }
}    

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly IServiceA _serviceA;

    public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
        serviceA.ServiceB = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although property injection is a solution for when one does not want to change the application's design, I believe that in the majority of cases, the there is a problem in the application's design that should be addressed first. Property injection is just addressing the symptom, not the cause. Still, I feel it's okay to give property injection as an answer, because it allows OP to choose from the available options. Unfortunately, your answer seems incomplete, as I'd expect you to show how to actually implement this using the OP's used DI Container (which probably is MS.DI).