# Trying to avoid circular dependency loop in the Service Collection DI

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

This is a websocket wrapper around [the Marfusios/websocket-client library](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client). `SocketHostedService` is a base websocket client abstraction with fire and forget `SendAsync`, request/response `RequestAsync` with a timeout.

The problem is `SocketApi` causes a circular dependency loop, and that's normal. All I wanted to do is have the base websocket client abstraction in the `SocketHostedService` and abstract the implementation in `SocketApi`. The handlers i.e. `Func<T, ValueTask> onSuccess`, etc. these that are passed to RequestAsync, should be abstracted into classes such as `LogonOperation`, `LogoffOperation`, etc. How do I avoid that circular dependency?

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CqgApi>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LogonOperation>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CqgHostService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<CqgHostService>());
```

```cs
public sealed class SocketHostedService : IHostedService, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly LogonOperation _logonOperation;
    private readonly CqgWebSocketClient _client;
    private readonly SocketApi _api;

    public SocketHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _client = new CqgWebSocketClient(new(settings.Value.Cqg.HostName),
            settings.Value.Cqg.Timeout, DisconnectActionAsync,
            ReconnectActionAsync);
        _api = new SocketApi(this);
        _logonOperation = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<LogonOperation>(
            serviceProvider, _api);
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) ...
    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) ...
    public async Task SendAsync<T>(IMessage<T> clientMessage)
        where T : IMessage<ClientMsg>, IMessage<T> ...
    public async Task RequestAsync(
        ClientMsg request, Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess,
        Func<string, ValueTask> onError, Func<ServerMsg, bool> matcher) ...
    private async Task ProcessServerResponse(ResponseMessage responseMessage) ...
    private Task DisconnectActionAsync(DisconnectionInfo info) ...
    
    private async Task ReconnectActionAsync(ReconnectionInfo info)
    {
        await AuthenticateAsync(serverMsg => _logonOperation
            .HandleResponse(serverMsg.LogonResult), onError =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("OnError = {OnError}", onError);
                return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            });
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SocketApi
{
    private readonly SocketHostedService _client;

    public SocketApi(SocketHostedService client) => _client = client;

    public async Task LogonAsync(
        string username, string password, Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess,
        Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        ...
        await _client.RequestAsync(..., onSuccess, onError, ...);
    }

    public async Task LogoffAsync(
        Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        ...
        await _client.RequestAsync(..., onSuccess, onError, ...);
    }

    public async Task GetAccountInformationAsync(
        Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        ...
        await _client.RequestAsync(..., onSuccess, onError, ...);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class LogonOperation
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogonOperation> _logger;
    private readonly SocketApi _api;

    public LogonOperation(ILogger<LogonOperation> logger, SocketApi api)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _api = api;
    }

    public async ValueTask HandleResponse(LogonResult logonResult)
    {
        var resultCodeName = Enum.GetName(
            typeof(LogonResult.Types.ResultCode),
            (LogonResult.Types.ResultCode)logonResult.ResultCode) ?? "Unspecified";

        switch (logonResult.ResultCode)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of your design are you willing to sacrifice? What part isn't actually your design (and cannot be changed)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services

Comment: @Fildor, the one thats in SocketHostedService